# Can an app that was removed from the Mac App Store be re-downloaded?

Tags: macos, mac-appstore, coda

I do a clean install whenever I upgrade my OS to a new major release.

I know Coda 1 is no longer in the App Store and isn't supported by Panic anymore but I'd like to keep using it because it works for my needs. I am curious whether Coda 1 can be re-downloaded on the Mac App Store under "Purchases" after I install a clean OS (particuarly Mountain Lion later this month)?

If not, can I copy the App to a USB drive and put it manually in to a cleanly installed OS and will it work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. Most cases the developer will leave the app on the store, but just remove it from being sellable to new owners.

That allows them to submit bug fixes for existing customers, not force them to upgrade, allow them to re-download things - but not have new buyers buying the wrong version (not the latest).

Of course, the developer or Apple can also remove the app entirely - but this is far less common. What is common is when the developer keeps the same name as far as the store is concerned. In this case, you'll want to have a backup that you control to re-install no matter what Apple or the developer chooses.

Comment: Thanks! I'll be sure to back it up but hopefully I will be able to simply re-download it from the App store.

Comment: In your case, you can email the fine folks at Panic. I'm sure they would explain how they have chosen to support Coda (the original series)

Answer (score 4):

You can back up the .app bundle and restore it at a later time. It'll work so long as you use the same apple id as before (due to code signing)

Answer (score 3):

This is possible in most cases.  Whilst ordinarily you may only download an App if it is available, and even then you may only download the most recent version of that app, in a number of circumstances it is possible to download an app that is no longer available.

The first obstacle is that if it is no longer available, then you cannot find it in order to download it.  They key is to find it on your purchase history section on the iTunes stores within iTunes.  If it's listed there, you should be able to download it regardless of it's availability to new users.

The most common reason for an app to become unavailable is for the developer to not renew his yearly $99 developer program fee.  This not only stops the developer from having access to the various tools etc, it also means that any apps they have in the store are removed.  Obviously in these cases it makes no sense to cause unnecessary hassle for legitimate purchasers who downloaded the App when it was legitimately available, and so these people always have this back door to re-download.

I believe the same applies for Apps that are pulled for breaking rules, if you downloaded it and Apple remove it, they only remove it for new downloaders.

Of course, it is possible just less common that the app has been removed due to malicious behaviour that was not caught in the review process.  In this case, then it's prudent to have access to it genuinely removed for good.